# Is there a way to control windows with Python?

Tags: python, linux, scripting, file-upload, web

I'm trying to create a script that will upload a file to a website. I have no control of the website so the file has to be uploaded via clicking and typing.

Aka,

1. wait for upload window to pop up
2. type name/path of file
3. click "Open" or "upload" (or whatever) button

Because the window is part of the OS (not a browser window), I can't control it with Selenium or something like that (as far as I know. Plz let me know if I am wrong). This means I need the script to do this.

I already have it working for Windows (made it with AutoIt) however, I also need it to run on Unix systems (Linux).

So I'm asking, is there a way to do it with Python or something? If I can make one script that will run on both, that would be awesome (AutoIt is Windows-only).

I have knowledge of Java, Python and AutoIt, but if none of those can do it, I can learn something else.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Ok, so apparently using HTTP POST is the way to do it, however I am not sure how to do this. I'm going to do more research on that. Thx @Chrules for bring this to my attention.

Comment: Sure you couldn't send a HTTP POST or GET request to the server?

Comment: IS your question about opening some windows on the screen in Python? Then PyGtk should fit well!

Comment: Unn, I'm not that familiar with HTTP POST and GET. I have used GET before but never POST, and I didn't think POST could post whole files. Can you give me an example of how I would do such I thing? 

@BasileStarynkevitch No, the window is being created by the site (you know, when a website asks for you to upload a file, a window comes up asking where the file is).

Comment: To code programmatically HTTP requests you can use `libcurl` see http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you want to do it via an HTTP request, the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library is highly recommended.

It is really that simple:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'report.xls': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```